# How to compare different values within the same column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I having two tables emp and type.

```
create table EMP(ID number(10), effective_date date);
EID    Effective_date
--------------------
1     02/14/2023
2     02/15/2023
3     04/30/2023
4     03/24/2023

create table type(ID number(10),contract_type varchar2(2));
TID  contract_type
------------------
1       P
1       S
1       P
2       S
2       S
3       P
3       S
4       S
```

I am looking EID which is having contract type is 'S' in type table. (or emp table with effective date is greater than sysdate and in the type table with only contract_type ='S')

### Actual result : 
2 
4

My query is not giving the correct results.

```
select emp.EID
 from emp,type
 where EID = TID
         contract_type ='S'
         effective_date >= sysdate
         group by TID 
         having count(TID) >= 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your idea with `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`, you should count other contract types than the 'S' ones and check this is 0:

```
SELECT e.eid
FROM emp e 
JOIN type t ON e.eid = t.tid
WHERE 
e.effective_date >= sysdate
GROUP BY e.eid 
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t.contract_type <> 'S' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

This query will return 2 and 4 for your sample data.

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z-DKR35S)

Another option is as already said here using `NOT EXISTS`.

Take care of following difference to the `NOT EXISTS` approach: The query in Tim's answer will also fetch id's of table "emp" that don't appear at all in table "type". My query here will not fetch such id's.

It's up to you to decide whether this is possible at all and what to do in this case.

Changing `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` in above query will eliminate this difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT EID
FROM EMP e
WHERE effective_date >= SYSDATE AND
      NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM "type" t
          WHERE t.TID = e.EID AND
                t.contract_type <> 'S'
      );
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. It helped me to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Count() Over() analytic function to check for type 'S' and number of different types per ID.

```sql
SELECT  DISTINCT ID
FROM    (   Select      e.EID "ID", 
                        Count(CASE t.CONTRACT_TYPE WHEN 'S' THEN 'S' END) Over(Partition By t.ID Order By t.ID) "NUM_OF_S",
                        Count(Distinct t.CONTRACT_TYPE) Over(Partition By t.ID) "NUM_OF_TYPES",
                        TRUNC(e.EFFECTIVE_DATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE) "DAYS_AFTER_SYSDATE"
            From        emp_cte e
            Inner Join  type_cte t ON(t.ID = e.EID)   )
WHERE   NUM_OF_S > 0 And         -- Type 'S' exists for ID  AND
        NUM_OF_TYPES = 1 And     -- It is the only type  AND
        DAYS_AFTER_SYSDATE > 0   -- EFFECTIVE_DATE is after SYSDATE
```

With your sample data  ...

```sql
WITH
    emp_cte(EID, EFFECTIVE_DATE) AS
        (
            Select 1, To_Date('02/14/2023', 'mm/dd/yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 2, To_Date('02/15/2023', 'mm/dd/yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 3, To_Date('04/30/2023', 'mm/dd/yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 4, To_Date('03/24/2023', 'mm/dd/yyyy') From Dual 
        ),
    type_cte(ID, CONTRACT_TYPE) AS
        (
            Select 1, 'P' From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 'S' From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 'P' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'S' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'S' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'P' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'S' From Dual Union All
            Select 4, 'S' From Dual 
        )
```

... result would be ...

```sql
--          ID
--  ----------
--           2 
--           4
```